# Constructing a regular expression that matches a filename pattern

Tags: python, regex

I'm having issues creating a regular expression that can match the following filename:

```
1253SOit_filename_20170315_131119.csv
```

I tried the following regex

```
"[0-9]{4}[a-z|A-Z]{2}_filename_\d{8}\_[0-9]{6}.csv"
```

with Python 2.6 but it does not match.

Comment: Try changing `[a-z|A-Z]{2}` to `[a-z|A-Z]{4}`

Comment: Try [`^\d{4}[A-Z]{2}[a-z]{2}_filename_\d{8}_\d{6}\.csv$`](https://regex101.com/r/ZIXrLM/1)

Comment: thanks you guys, that fixed the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `[a-z|A-Z]{2}` you could use `[A-Z]{2}` and `[a-z]{2}` to match `SOit`.

To match the dot before .csv you could escape it `\.`

Try it like this:

[`[0-9]{4}[A-Z]{2}[a-z]{2}_filename_\d{8}_[0-9]{6}\.csv`](https://regex101.com/r/GUb25w/2)